# how to get specific list from database on onclick of a particular item in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have two tables in my database 
Placetype and Place

placetype consists of all the placetypes like resturaunt, hotel, motel etc

now i want when a user click on resturaunt for eg, he gets all the returaunt list and not all the places other then resturaunt. i am unable to do this. please help...

here is my code:

Database.java

```
     package com.example.nearbyplaces;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String db_name = "nearby_place";
    private static final int db_version = 1;

    //tables
        private static final String table_placetypes = "placetypes";
        private static final String table_places = "table_places";

        //column names
        private static final String type_id = "type_id";
        private static final String type_name = "type_name";
        private static final String place_id = "place_id";
        private static final String place_name = "place_name";
        private static final String place_address = "place_address";
        private static final String place_contact = "place_contact";


        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, db_name, null, db_version);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        // create table queries
        String create_table_placetypes = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + table_placetypes + "("
                + type_id + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," + type_name + " TEXT" + ")";



        String create_table_places = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_places (place_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, place_name TEXT, place_address TEXT, place_contact TEXT, type_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES table_placetypes(type_id))";



        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL(create_table_placetypes);

            Log.d("creating", "placetypes created");
            db.execSQL(create_table_places);
            Log.d("creating", "places created");


        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_placetypes);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_places);
            onCreate(db);

        }
        // add placetypes 
        void addplacetypes (placetypes pt) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

            values.put(type_name, pt.getTypename());

            db.insert(table_placetypes, null, values);
            db.close();

        }

         // Getting single placetypes
        placetypes getPlacetypes(int id) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.query(table_placetypes, new String[] {type_id,
                    type_name }, type_id + "=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            placetypes pt = new placetypes(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                    cursor.getString(1));
            // return contact
            return pt;
        }

     // Getting All placetypes
        public List<placetypes> getAllPlacetypes() {
            List<placetypes> placetypesList = new ArrayList<placetypes>();
            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + table_placetypes;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    placetypes pt = new placetypes();
                    pt.setTypeid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    pt.setTypename(cursor.getString(1));


                    //String name = cursor.getString(1);

                    //MainActivity.ArrayofName.add(name);
                    // Adding contact to list
                    placetypesList.add(pt);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // return placetype list
            return placetypesList;
    }

        // Getting placetypes Count
        public int getPlacetypesCount() {
            String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + table_placetypes;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
            cursor.close();

            // return count
            return cursor.getCount();
        }

        public void addplaces(places p) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(place_name, p.getPlace_name());
            values.put(place_address, p.getPlace_address());
            values.put(place_contact, p.getPlace_contact());
            values.put(type_id, p.getT_id());

            Log.d("Type ID", String.valueOf(p.getT_id()));
            db.insert(table_places, null, values);
            db.close();

        }

        places getPlaces(int pid) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query(table_places, new String[] {place_id, place_name, place_address, place_contact,type_id}, place_id + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(pid) } , null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor != null)
                 cursor.moveToFirst();

            places p = new places(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                    Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)),
                    cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3),
                    cursor.getString(4)
                    );

            cursor.close();

            return p;

        }

        public List<places> getAllPlaces(String typeName) {

            List<places> placeList = new ArrayList<places>();
            //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM table_places INNER JOIN placetypes ON placetypes.type_id=table_places.type_id "; 
            //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM table_places WHERE table_places.type_id="+Integer.toString(typeid);
            //String selectQuery ="SELECT * FROM table_places WHERE table_places.place_name = " +typeName+ "INNER JOIN placetypes ON placetypes.type_id = table_places.type_id";
            //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM table_places INNER JOIN placetypes ON placetypes.type_id = table_places.type_id WHERE table_places.place_name = " + typeName + "";
            //String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +table_places;
            String selectQuery ="SELECT * FROM table_places INNER JOIN placetypes ON placetypes.type_id=table_places.type_id WHERE placetypes.type_name='"+typeName+"'";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


            if(cursor.moveToFirst() )
            {
                do{
                places p = new places();
                /*p.setT_id(cursor.getColumnIndex(type_id));
                p.setPlace_id(cursor.getColumnIndex(place_id));
                p.setPlace_name(cursor.getColumnIndex(place_name));
                */
                p.setT_id(cursor.getInt(0));
                p.setPlace_id(cursor.getInt(1));
                p.setPlace_name(cursor.getString(2));
                p.setPlace_address(cursor.getString(3));
                p.setPlace_contact(cursor.getString(4));

                /*String t_id = cursor.getString(4);
                String p_name = cursor.getString(2);
                String p_address = cursor.getString(3);
                String p_contact = cursor.getString(1);*/

                placeList.add(p);
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();
            return placeList;
        }

        public int getPlaceCount () {

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " +table_places;
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(create_table_places, null);
            cursor.close();

            return cursor.getCount();
        }

}
```

MainActivity2

```
 package com.example.nearbyplaces;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;




import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {

    private ListView listView;
    public static ArrayList<String> ArrayofName = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        Intent check = getIntent();
        String x = check.getStringExtra(MainActivity.PLACETYPE);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), x, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
         if(db.getAllPlaces(x).isEmpty())
         {
         /**
             * CRUD Operations
             * */
            // Inserting Places2
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.addplaces(new places("Pizza Hut", "abc", "123",1));
            //db.addplaces(new places("Pizza Hut",null,null));
           /* db.addplacetypes(new placetypes("MALLS"));
            db.addplacetypes(new placetypes("GAS STATIONS"));
            db.addplacetypes(new placetypes("HOTELS"));
            db.addplacetypes(new placetypes("MOTELS")); 
         */}
            // Reading all Places
            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all places..");

            if(ArrayofName.isEmpty())
            {
                List<places> places = db.getAllPlaces(x);
                for (places p : places) 
                {
                    String log = "Id: "+p.getPlace_id() +" ,Name: " + p.getPlace_name() +" ,ADDRESS: " + p.getPlace_address() +"CONTACT NO. : " +p.getPlace_contact();
                     //Writing Places to log
                    Log.d("Name: ", log);
                    Log.d("ADDRESS: ", log);
                    Log.d("CONTACT NO : ", log);

                    System.out.println(log);
                    ArrayofName.add(p.getPlace_name());
                  //  ArrayofName.add(p.getPlace_address());
                  //  ArrayofName.add(p.getPlace_contact());
                }
            }   

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayofName);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
                    {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      // Intent i = new Intent(this,Activity2.class);
                      // startActivity(i);
                      // Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                      // startActivity(intent);


                    }
                }
            );
    }

}
```

Logcat

```
    10-11 19:34:31.160: D/Reading:(12694): Reading all placetypes..
10-11 19:34:31.164: D/Name:(12694): Id: 1 ,Name: RESTURAUNTS
10-11 19:34:31.164: I/System.out(12694): Id: 1 ,Name: RESTURAUNTS
10-11 19:34:31.164: D/Name:(12694): Id: 2 ,Name: MALLS
10-11 19:34:31.164: I/System.out(12694): Id: 2 ,Name: MALLS
10-11 19:34:31.164: D/Name:(12694): Id: 3 ,Name: GAS STATIONS
10-11 19:34:31.164: I/System.out(12694): Id: 3 ,Name: GAS STATIONS
10-11 19:34:31.164: D/Name:(12694): Id: 4 ,Name: HOTELS
10-11 19:34:31.164: I/System.out(12694): Id: 4 ,Name: HOTELS
10-11 19:34:31.164: D/Name:(12694): Id: 5 ,Name: MOTELS
10-11 19:34:31.164: I/System.out(12694): Id: 5 ,Name: MOTELS
10-11 19:34:31.230: D/libEGL(12694): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-11 19:34:31.234: D/libEGL(12694): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-11 19:34:31.246: D/libEGL(12694): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-11 19:34:31.300: D/OpenGLRenderer(12694): Enabling debug mode 0
10-11 19:34:33.320: D/Insert:(12694): Inserting ..
10-11 19:34:33.320: D/Type ID(12694): 1
10-11 19:34:33.355: D/Reading:(12694): Reading all places..
10-11 19:34:33.363: D/Name:(12694): Id: 0 ,Name: abc ,ADDRESS: 123CONTACT NO. : 1
10-11 19:34:33.363: D/ADDRESS:(12694): Id: 0 ,Name: abc ,ADDRESS: 123CONTACT NO. : 1
10-11 19:34:33.363: D/CONTACT NO :(12694): Id: 0 ,Name: abc ,ADDRESS: 123CONTACT NO. : 1
10-11 19:34:33.363: I/System.out(12694): Id: 0 ,Name: abc ,ADDRESS: 123CONTACT NO. : 1
10-11 19:34:50.090: D/Insert:(12766): Inserting ..
10-11 19:34:50.090: D/Type ID(12766): 1
10-11 19:34:50.113: D/Reading:(12766): Reading all places..
10-11 19:36:08.488: D/Insert:(12877): Inserting ..
10-11 19:36:08.488: D/Type ID(12877): 1
10-11 19:36:08.511: D/Reading:(12877): Reading all places..
```

Comment: Is the place type extra that is being sent to Acivity2 the name of the type?

Comment: yes i was trying this thing, but was not so useful

Comment: Edited answer. I thought you were passing in the type id.

Comment: same error in mainActivity.. its not letting me pass anything in the function being called

Comment: Could you update your post with the current code you are now running, and the error log?

Comment: updated code is posted.. the error log shows two errors 

Description Resource Path Location Type
The method getAllPlaces(String) in the type Database is not applicable for the arguments () MainActivity2.java /Nearby_Places/src/com/example/nearby_places line 33 Java Problem
The method getAllPlaces(String) in the type Database is not applicable for the arguments () MainActivity2.java /Nearby_Places/src/com/example/nearby_places line 52 Java Problem

Comment: Make sure you save both files, and then do Project -> Clean. It's saying that your method doesn't have a String parameter.

Comment: Ok, so now the errors are gone.. I will run it now and will let you know in couple of minutes. Thanks

Comment: Gives me error in my select query inner join @getAllPlaces

Comment: Oops sorry, the SQL syntax I gave you was bad. I've updated it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help .. i will update you in sometime

Comment: It worked, Thanks alot man. But i don't know why its showing me the adress instead of name. in places.. can u just check my code if i update it?

Comment: The code is updated .. please check why id = 0 and rest of the fields are jumbled up

Comment: It looks alright to me. Check my answer and try that output logging. It looks like you only have one place with under that type, right? And that place's id is 0.

Comment: No that place id is 1, i checked my database file

Comment: My only guess is that your columns are not returning in the order you expect. You could try implementing what I said before, using getColumnIndex instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: The whole problem is solved, thanks a lot. 
can u help me with one last thing? i want the other 2 fields (address & contact) from place's table in new activity. m trying something but its giving me null pointer exception. Kindly look over at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to limit your query. Add a parameter to getAllPlaces:

```
public List<places> getAllPlaces(String typeName) {
```

And change your query string to:

```
String selectQuery ="SELECT * FROM table_places INNER JOIN placetypes ON placetypes.type_id=table_places.type_id WHERE placetypes.place_name='"+typeName+"'";
```

Now wherever you call getAllPlaces, call it with the type name:

```
if(db.getAllPlaces(x).isEmpty())
...
List<places> places = db.getAllPlaces(x);
```

EDIT:
For your output issue, I think what you want is:

```
//String log = "Id: "+p.getPlace_id() +" ,Name: " + p.getPlace_name() +" ,ADDRESS: " + p.getPlace_address() +"CONTACT NO. : " +p.getPlace_contact();
 //Writing Places to log
Log.d("Test", "Id: "+p.getPlace_id());
Log.d("Test", "Name: "+p.getPlace_name());
Log.d("Test", "Address: "+p.getPlace_address());
Log.d("Test", "Contact No.: "+p.getPlace_contact());
```

Comment: it gives me error in main activity 2 where my intent is being called from main activity. while inserting records m using this function.. when i give the parameter the error pops up in activity class

Comment: what it this x in if condition ?

Comment: Check your activity 2, that is what you assign the type name to.

Comment: its not letting me add anything in the function name that is getAllPlaces(x).. i get the red line at getAllPlaces

Comment: Did you change the getAllPlaces method like I said in step 1 of my answer?